# how to replace R.drawable.* with url image

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
private Integer[] ImgIds = { R.drawable.kk,
                            R.drawable.ww,
                            R.drawable.dd,
                            R.drawable.ee,
                            R.drawable.ff,
                            R.drawable.gg };
```

now i want to load the images from the url(e.g. `http://liquidcreativestudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/tv-icon.png`)

and i still need Integer[] ImgIds..
R.drawable.* and the url has same image
is there any way so that i can put the ids of images from url in my array.
and further i need to use this url images to set some imageviews..

Comment: if R.drawable and url has same image then y use url...??

Answer (score 0):

```
private Integer[] ImgIds = { R.drawable.kk,
                            R.drawable.ww,
                            R.drawable.dd,
                            R.drawable.ee,
                            R.drawable.ff,
                            R.drawable.gg };


String path = getResources().getString(ImgIds[i]);
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between setting the image of an imageView from R.drawable id wich is a local image and setting it from internet resource. in the second case you need to

- fetch the url into inputStream
- transform that inputStream into Drawable
- Set that drawable to the imageView

[here](http://bit.ly/LUAXcX) you can find a good tutorial that can help you.